# How to check DNS?

Tags: dns, ping, system-administration, cloudflare

When troubleshooting DNS issues (specifically whether a domain is resolving), what is the proper way to check so that you get accurate results? DNS info is cached throughout the internet, and different machines (like local machine) or service (like pingdom) has different results.

How to check the DNS so that you know what you will get after it propagates?

Working with Heroku and CloudFlare.

Answer (score 2):

In most common cases you can use tools such as: **dig** or **host**. Both tools are made for query name servers to retrieve info. You can also use a simple "**ping something.domain.com**" in order to see if IP has changed. But I suggest you to use different DNS's on the computer you're using to test. Actually Google DNS replicate so fast ( 8.8.8.8 ).

Not on purpose DNS poisoning: Keep in mind if you're pinging something that is recently configured/changed on your name server and still not propagated you'll "poison" the DNS's cache and this data is going to expire, but later...( [Always depending on domain name TTL's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) of course ).
Using a new DNS wich never has known that domain you're sure the request is made for the first time and it's going to be made without asking any cache.

Example:

**To get all the DNS servers for domain.com:**

> **$ host -t ns domain.com**
>
> domain.com name server ns2.domain.com.
>
> domain.com name server ns3.domain.com.

**To ask a domain name for something.domain.com:**

> **$ dig @nameserver something.domain.com**

You can also ask for TXT, CNAME types and so on...

Examples:

**AXFR retrieval test:**

> **$ dig @domainname domain.com AXFR**

**Or get all Mail Exchange (MX) server for a domain:**

> **$ host -t MX domain.com**
>
> domain.com mail is handled by 10 smtp.godo.com.
>
> domain.com mail is handled by 20 smtp2.godo.com.

Hope it helps.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup

To get a "Non-authoritative" answer from your local name server that would be e.g.:

```
nslookup test.com
```

To check the name server where the domain is listed that would be e.g.:

```
nslookup test.com nameServerOfTest.com
```